# How to execute a task in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, embedded

I have been working on embedded project with IAR for a long time. We are now trying other IDE, because IAR is not the most up to date one. I am now trying VS (Visual Studio and NOT Visual Studio Code). In the local setting (.vs folder), there is a file named task.vs.json. How can I execute a task defined in this file?

In the Microsoft documentation, it is said that the task can be called from the solution conext menu. I did not found the task there... Do I need to execute something so VS can recognized the task? In hte Task Runner Explorer, no task is found in the project. Maybe it is because there is an error in the tasks.vs.json file.. Here is the content of tasks.vs.sjon :

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskLabel": "task-flash",
      "appliesTo": "tools/flash.bat",
      "type": "launch"
    }
  ]
}
```

I took the tasks.vs.json file from the repo https://github.com/azure-rtos/getting-started. I am using the NXP/MIMXRT1060-EVK/ project example.

Thank you,